# Close Simplemodal

Tags: simplemodal

how to close a window open as SimpleModal iframe?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for:

```
$.modal.close();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can also add classname to your close button "simplemodal-close"